# No User Stories in backlog navigation levels (Azure Devops)

Tags: azure-devops, settings, agile, backlog, sprint

I can't see where to activate User Stories for my DevOps. I only have Epics and Issues. Where can I change this?

[image]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Backlog elements are dependent on the chosen project process as project creation. The backlogs defined for each default process are:

- Agile: Stories, Features, and Epics
- Basic: Issues and Epics
- Scrum: Backlog items, Features, and Epics
- CMMI: Requirements, Features, and Epics

As seen in the official documentation, the process implemententing Stories in backlogs is Agile. You have probably set up your project as Basic.

To change this, you need to go to the Organisational settings and then change the process.
Microsoft has a page exactly dedicated to this exact change with clear defined instructions with screenshots:

[Changing Process from Basic to Agile](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/organizations/settings/work/change-process-basic-to-agile?view=azure-devops)

For further projects, just use the process Agile and it will be available as default.